# How to access the framebuffer in modern Android devices?

Tags: android, framebuffer

*I am working on rooted devices. Also, I don't have a lot of experience with android, so please point me to resources that would be easy to follow through.*

I am trying to access the framebuffer of an Android device in a reliable fashion. I found out that /dev/graphics/fb0 would let me do that. My Xperia Z just seems to spout out 0s and apparently this is common in modern devices.

I came across the screenrecord executable, pre-Lollipop versions don't stream raw data, so I am at a loss again.

So, if I want to access the frame buffer, and continuously forward it to an app, or through adb, how can I do it?